# Creating simple loops

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm trying to create a basic loop but I am struggling to find information online.

All I want to do is use a loop rather than subsetting my data and repeating the same commands for each.

For example:
I have a dataset (`animals`) which is looking at different `animal.type` (dogs, horses, cats, mice) and I have separated them into `coat` colour (black, red, brown, white) and taken the `weights` at different `ages`. I have a series of commands e.g. change data to a linear grouped model (lmer), view the data, do an anova, look at the summary data, check model assumptions etc etc. I only want to do statistics on one type of `animal.type` at a time. Rather than subsetting to `dogs` or `horses` and repeating the same formula over and over again, I want to make a loop which will repeat the same statistics for each `animal.type`.

What is the simplest way to do this?

I would expect it would be something like...

```
loop? <- function(animals$animal.type){
ggplot() #view data
lmer1 <- lmer(weight~coat*age) #Create linear model
anova(lmer1)  #look for main patterns
summary(lmer1) #model coefficients
lmerTest::lsmeans(lmer1,test.effs="coat:age") #check model assumptions
plot(lmer1)}
```

I know this isn't right, but I'm sure the answer is out there ... I just cant find it.

Comment: "Struggling to find information online"? Where have you looked?

Comment: What language are you attempting to do this in?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for (atype in unique(animals$animal.type)) {
     dd <- subset(animals,animal.type==atype)
     ggplot(dd,...)
     lmer1 <- lmer(weight~coat*age + (1|something), data=dd)
     anova(lmer1)
     summary(lmer1)
     lmerTest::lsmeans(lmer1,test.effs="coat:age")
     plot(lmer1)
}
```